# Can I install other distro and use /home from previous one?

Tags: ubuntu, software-installation, crunchbang

I want to install CrunchBang, and I have been using Ubuntu 12.10.

Should I format `/home`, or do I need to only format `/` and install #! there?

Answer (score 2):

there is no reason the install/re-install `/home`. actually one of the reasons for having `/home` on a separate partition is to make it independent of the actual system.

at work, i still use NFS-mounted `/home` partitions for many systems.

Answer (score 1):

It should not create serious problems to keep the `/home` folder. As ChrunchBang is like Ubuntu a Debian-based distribution, most programs should find their configuration files.
If not, they will create new one.

It is more or less like up/downgrading between different Ubuntu versions.

You need to bear in mind some disadvantages:

- Incompatibilities could arise. Then you need to delete/rename the corresponding configurations files or directories by hand.
- Unneeded/Out-dated configuration and cache files are left in your home directory.

Answer (score 0):

I usually just do a install/re-install over anything pre-existing, but you could always try it. You'll likely run into issues with much of the configuration files that are stored in the user's home directory for the setup of the windowing environment (Xfce, GNOME, etc.).

If you want to keep things around you can always tar everything up and keep just the tarball file around in case you want to grab a configuration or setup file from the previous installation.

Comment: Why wipe then install? Won't an install overwrite whatever exists? Or is it a precaution for privacy/security reasons?

Comment: @vasa1 - sorry I didn't mean a literal wipe, I'll update my answer taking that out.

Comment: Just wiping the hidden dirs in /home is the best option.